# MS Word - add page number to multiple cross-references

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a large word document with multiple cross-references to figures, tables etc.

How can I add a page number to these references?

So, for example, "See Table 2" would become "See Table 2 (p. 123)".

Is this possible? Perhaps with a Macro or VB script?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know of any way to make a single, unified cross-reference
that includes both a label&number
(e.g., Table *n*, Figure *n*, or Equation *n*) and also a page number —
but you can certainly do it
with two separate cross-references to the same item/caption:

[image]

I spent five minutes recording a macro to take a “Figure *n*” reference
and add “ (page *num*)”:

```
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:=" (page "
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
Selection.TypeText Text:=")"
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=4
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=8
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
Selection.TypeText Text:="PAGE"
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
Selection.Fields.Update
```

Just insert your “Figure *n*” cross-reference and run the above.  It

- copies the reference you just created,
- inserts “ `(page` ”,
- pastes the cross-reference,
- inserts “`)`”,
- moves back (to the left) and selects the cross-reference, and
- edits the cross-reference, changing `REF` to `PAGEREF`.

I expect that this will work equally with Tables and Equations,
and (possibly with some modifications) with section headings.

Comment: It would not traverse the whole document though, would it? I guess it could be possible to write a macro based on this which goes through the whole document and changes Figure, Equation and Table references..